# Is there an explanation for this R function merge() error?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to use the R `merge` function to combine two data.frames, but keep getting the following error:

> Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

I am not sure what this error means or how to resolve it.

My code thus far is the following:

```
movies <- read_csv("movies.csv")

firsts = vector(length = nrow(movies))
for (i in 1:nrow(movies)) {
  firsts[i] = movies$director[i] %>% str_split(" ", n = 2) %>% unlist %>% .[1]
}

movies$firsts = firsts

movies <- movies[-c(137, 147, 211, 312, 428, 439, 481, 555, 602, 830, 850, 1045, 1080, 1082, 1085, 1096, 1255, 1258, 1286, 1293, 1318, 1382, 1441, 1456, 1494, 1509, 1703, 1719, 1735, 1944, 1968, 1974, 1977, 2098, 2197, 2409, 2516, 2546, 2722, 2751, 2988, 3191,
3227, 3270, 3283, 3285, 3286, 3292, 3413, 3423, 3470, 3480, 3511, 3676, 3698, 3826, 3915, 3923, 3954, 4165, 4381, 4385, 4390, 4397, 4573, 4711, 4729, 4774, 4813, 4967, 4974, 5018, 5056, 5258, 5331, 5405, 5450, 5469, 5481, 4573, 5708, 5715, 5786, 5886, 5888, 5933, 5934, 6052, 6091, 6201, 6234, 6236, 6511, 6544, 6551, 6562, 6803, 4052, 4121, 4326),]
movies <- movies[-c(4521,5846),]

g <- gender_df(movies, name_col = "firsts", year_col = "year", method = c("ssa"))

merge(movies, g, by = c("firsts", "name"), all = FALSE)
```

Comment: What is the output of `base::intersect(names(movies),names(g))`?!

Comment: The output I think is, "name". Sorry, I am new to R.

Comment: What is the function `gender_df`? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data and the *minimal* code needed for the issue

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you are trying to give the `by` argument a non-valid value. Indeed, the documentation tells:

> By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they
>   both have, but separate specifications of the columns can be given by
>   by.x and by.y. The rows in the two data frames that match on the
>   specified columns are extracted, and joined together. If there is more
>   than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each. For the
>   precise meaning of ‘match’, see match.

In your case, you shall try the following:

```
merge(x = movies,y =  g, by.x = "firsts", by.y = "name", all = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! It not longer returns an error, but my resulting dataframe contains many more observations than the two dataframes I am merging. Do you happen to know why this is occurring?

Comment: I could guess that `merge()` made this happen. It can occur with the joining of two dataframes: each single value of X is associated with each tuple of Y. Is your new number of observations a mutliple of one of your data frames?
I searched about your 'gender_df' function, and couldn't find any package mentioning it. Could you tell me more about it and/or write its specification? I just had a thought about the merge() function and the syntax of this function.

Comment: It worked now, thank you! I had forgot I made a mistake with syntax is some prior code utilizing gender_df. Thank you for your help:)